Why doesn't \centering center the last line?
My code:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
{
  \centering

  Foo

  Bar

  Baz

  Quz
}
\end{document}

Output:

Why isn't the last line ("Quz") centered in the output?
I know how to fix it. I need to add a blank line before the closing brace. Like so.
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
{
  \centering

  Foo

  Bar

  Baz

  Quz

}
\end{document}

Fixed output:

But I want to know why in the first example, the last line is not centered?

\centering acts when you end the paragraph. Which is done by either a blank line, or the \par command. This holds also for a single line : {\centering a line} don't center the text, while {\centering a line\par} works. If you can manage some extra vertical space, you could use center environment, where the final \par is not needed.

@Jhor you don't have to add it explicitly, you mean, because the environment will end the paragraph for you?

As Jhor explained in a comment, \centering acts on the current paragraph. In your case, you are confining the effect of \centering to a local group delimited by { ... }, so \centering's effect ends with the closing }.
{ % <start local group> then <space>
  \centering % <centre paragraphs until end of group or other command ends effect>
  % <new paragraph>

  Foo % <F> then <o> then <o> then <space> then <new paragraph>

  Bar % <B> then <a> then <r> then <space> then <new paragraph>

  Baz % <B> then <a> then <z> then <space> then <new paragraph>

  Quz % <Q> then <u> then <z> then <space>
} % <end local group>

The final } ends the local group and, so the effect of \centering, in the middle of the final paragraph. There is a space after the Quz but no paragraph break.
\end{document}

Among other things, this ends the final paragraph. So this final paragraph is typeset with the default settings i.e. the settings which applied before TeX began the local group containing \centering.
Whatever paragraph-shaping options apply at the end of the paragraph apply to that entire paragraph. So, in this case, the final paragraph will be subject to TeX's standard algorithm for (potentially) justified text. (Obviously, it is too short for this, but that's the active formatting.)
Consider the following example,
{
  \centering

  Foo

  Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar

  Bar Bar Bar Bar Bar
  \raggedright

  \raggedright
  Baz Baz \raggedleft Baz Baz Baz

  Quz
}

To predict the result, note which, if any, of \centering, \raggedright or \raggedleft is active when the paragraph ends.

Note that it doesn't matter how many paragraph-shaping commands there are before or in the text of the paragraph. The effective command can even follow the end of the paragraph's text, provided the paragraph itself has not yet been completed.

It might be worth adding some text after the group to emphasize that } does not end a paragraph started inside the group.

What would you expect to happen if there is text after the closing of the group or before you open the group for the centering?
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
foo 

{\centering  bar}bar
  
foo{\centering  foo\par}  
\end{document}

The begin of the paragraph then gives conflicting instructions at the begin and the end of the paragraph and TeX has decided that the end wins (but remark that the \noindent from \centering is still there in the bar case).


Let's look at the definition of \centering (from latex.ltx):
\DeclareRobustCommand\centering{%
  \let\\\@centercr
  \rightskip\@flushglue\leftskip\@flushglue
  \finalhyphendemerits=\z@
  \parindent\z@\parfillskip\z@skip}

Note that it sets a number of elements like \rightskip and \leftskip. Now look at the following discussion in TeX by Topic:

17.2 Assorted remarks
17.2.1 Ending a paragraph and a group at the same time
If a paragraph is set in a group, it may be necessary to ensure that the \par ending the paragraph occurs inside the group. The parameters influencing the typesetting of the paragraph, such as the \leftskip and the \baselineskip, are only looked at when the paragraph is finished. Thus finishing off a paragraph with
... last words.}\par

causes the values to be used that prevail outside the group, instead of those inside. Better ways to end the paragraph are
... last words.\par}

or
... last words.\medskip}

In the second example the vertical command \medskip causes the \par token to be inserted.

In your first example, the final line is followed by a blank line (equivalent to a \par), which "closes off the paragraph for processing and setting." As such, the appropriate values of \rightskip and \leftskip (and others) are used.
In the second example, the paragraph is "closed off" after the group has ended. Due to the closure of the group, changed values revert to what they were set outside the group (similar to a justified setting), leaving the final paragraph set without the settings associated with \centering.

Note that a carriage return (and line feed) is different from a blank line (\par).

More simply, consider
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % to show the margins

\begin{document}

{\centering AAAAAA}

\end{document}


What happened? The paragraph was started under the scope of \centering, so there is no indentation. But it ends outside the scope of \centering.
By design, TeX reads a whole paragraph before starting to typeset it. At the beginning, TeX is in “vertical mode” or, with a simpler term, “between paragraphs”. After seeing something that starts a paragraph, in this case the first A, it does a few things:

adds the \parskip glue;

starts horizontal mode;

inserts an indentation box of width \parindent, using the current value;

stores the whole paragraph in memory, until finding \par (or anything else that forces it).


At this point TeX breaks the paragraph into lines and typesets it. Using the relevant parameter values that are current when \par is processed.
In the case above, as well as in yours, the paragraph ending is found after }, so the values current at the matching { are used. As a consequence, justification is applied.
Why does
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % to show the margins

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
material
\end{figure}

\end{document}

works as expected? Because \end{figure} issues \par.
